# How to set UILabel to UIButton for forState:UIControlEventTouchDown?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have to set a `UILabel` to `UIButton` `forState:UIControlEventTouchDown`.
but button does not have set label property. Is anybody have idea about this ... let me know.
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a UILabel on a UIButton. I think what you mean is to see the title of the UIButton.

To do that you do:

`[myButton setTitle@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton` does not have *label* property. It has **setTitle** property. You need to set title of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Why do u want to use a label?? instead you Can use setTitle:forState: for UIButton. [see the class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Comment: in uilabel i want to set a text which present parsed data.parsing i done only i want to set that label of parsed data for uicontroleventtouchdown.so its isnot possible to settitle to it

Comment: do you want to change the text of a label on press of a button?? if so, you can use IBAction for that button and inside IBAction you can set text to the label.  `yourLabel.text=yourParsedStringName;`

Comment: i have to change it programatically .not through IBAction

Comment: @triveni: even what I told is also doing programmatically only.

Answer (score 0):

Just put one Button & set as a custom Button & for your satisfaction you can put UILabel on that button...but user interaction for that UILabel set as

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 purpleBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 purpleBtn.frame = CGRectMake(422, 173, 58, 77);
 [purpleBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"purplebtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [purpleBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(purplebtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [purpleBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 [purpleBtn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [self.view addSubview: purpleBtn];
```